# why TypeOrm slow when using Where in operator

Tags: sql, express, typeorm

i am using the typeorm where in operators where i get the max(date) for each location and after about 70 location it returns the data after 90 second where in sql server takes only 5 seconds.

this is what i got so far this code works but the after alot of unsynclocations it slows that to the point it wont rerurn data anymore.

```
  const getLastTimeIn = await getRepository(TimeInOut)
  .createQueryBuilder("TimeInOut")
  .select(["max(DateTrans) as date"])
  .where("location IN (:...location)")
  .setParameters({ location: unsyncLocations })
  .groupBy("location")
  .getRawMany();
```

i also tried looping the locations but it seems much slower than the code above

```
for (let i = 0; i < unsyncLocations.length; i++) {
  const element = unsyncLocations[i];
  const getLastTimeIn = await getRepository(TimeInOut)
    .createQueryBuilder("TimeInOut")
    .select("top 1 DateTrans")
    .where("location = :location")
    .setParameters({ location: element })
    .orderBy("DateTrans", "DESC")
    .getRawMany();
  console.log(getLastTimeIn);
  await unsyncData.push({
    id: id,
    location: element,
    DateTrans: this.dateFormater(getLastTimeIn[0].DateTrans)
  });
  id++;
}
```

this is the entity for the timeinout

```
@Entity("TimeInOut")
export class TimeInOut {
  @PrimaryColumn("int")
  ID: number;
  @Column("datetime")
  DateTrans: string;
  @Column("int")
  Attrib1: string;
  @Column("varchar", { length: 30 })
  Attrib2: string;
  @Column("int")
  Attrib3: string;
  @Column("int")
  Attrib4: string;
  @Column("int")
  IsSync: string;
  @Column("varchar", { length: 100 })
  location: string;
  @Column("datetime")
  timeStampLog: string;
  @Column("varchar", { length: 500 })
  CompanyId: string;
  @Column("varchar", { length: 500 })
  sourcelocation: string;
}
```

here is the equivalent query

```
select Max(DateTrans)  from TimeInOut where location in ('location1','location2',etc...)
```

the output will be

```
dateTrans 
9/29/2019
9/29/2019
```

Comment: Try sharing a bit more information. Code, schema, queries would be helpful.

Comment: @evert sorry i just finished editing it

Comment: Can you also share your database schema?

Comment: hi @Evert  thanks for helping out i just edit the post for my entyties

Comment: I don't see any indexes. If you're dealing with a reasonably large dataset, indexes might really help here. I also find it a little suspicious that location is a string and not an integer, but you probably know best here.

Comment: What do you mean by indexes? Like a primary id? I cant have a primary id or auto generated id because the prod databse has no auto generated or primary key.. And also the location is a string with varchar lenght of 100

Comment: An index is a SQL feature that allows a sql server to quickly find or filter data from a large dataset. The concept is the same as an index at the back of a book. If your table is at a size where you are experience slowdowns, often one of the first places to look at is: What are my actual queries? How does the server execute them (EXPLAIN SELECT) and then pick the right (set of) columns to create indexes for. If you're completely new to the concept of an index, this is what you should be learning.

Comment: Ok it but the sql server has no problem at all my problem is with the typeorm who is slowing down

Comment: Is TypeORM generating the exact same query as you are?

Comment: yes but much slower because i tried small data and it works the only problem is its slower

Comment: Then share that query and the output of EXPLAIN SELECT.

Comment: ok i have edit the question